Getting NULL POINTER EXCEPTION while re-routing the record to DLQ kafka Topic
i think i bumped into a known issue which is being discussed on this thread https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/issues/221
the error logs for the same are
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.buffer(org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkRecord)" because the return value of "java.util.Map.get(Object)" is null at io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask.put(S3SinkTask.java:225) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:601) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:350) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:250) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:219) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:204) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:259) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:237) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
From the shared disussion thread, it appears the PR is complete. However, I'm unsure if any additional testing is required. For your reference, here's the PR: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/pull/480.

Request the committers to please review n merge it. !!
